# Difference between ways of rooting device

Tags: rooting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can't the su binary simply be copied (techical response please)](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/27321/why-cant-the-su-binary-simply-be-copied-techical-response-please)

What is the difference between flashing device with root ROM and simple pushing su utility to device using adb without flashing it?

If I don't need to launch applications which need a root functionality, but just need to relocate some files in android file system, using su, do I need to flash my device?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my understanding, the end result is the same in both cases, it's just the rooting methods that differ. Some devices have vulnerabilities that can be exploited in order to push the `su` binary to the device via `adb` ([example](http://www.apriorit.com/our-company/dev-blog/255-android-rooting)), but these do not exist in all devices. This is why flashing is required sometimes.

TL;DR: It depends on your device.

Comment: Correct me if I wrong. Flashing device, you change it's file system and inflate it with some new system tools such as su?

Comment: Yes, you basically copy the `su` binary straight to the file system with the correct permissions, bypassing Android's file system security.